# Same Kinds for List of Int compared to List of Int -> Int?

Tags: haskell

Why do both of these have the same kind?

```
ghci> :k [Int]
[Int] :: *
ghci> :k [Int -> Int]
[Int -> Int] :: *
```

**EDIT** per @[Gabriel Gonzalez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1026598/gabriel-gonzalez)'s helpful comment.

I don't understand `kinds` well, so I don't have a good basis for expecting the above types to vary in `kind`.

Comment: An example of something with a higher kind would be `Maybe :: * -> *`.  Maybe you should explain why you thought `[Int -> Int]` would have a kind other than `*`.

Comment: If you have something that could be the type of a valid haskell expression it's always of kind `*`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, let's check.

```
Int :: *
[] :: * -> *
```

So when you apply the `Int` type to the `[]` type constructor:

```
[] Int :: *
```

Which is just another (legal) way of writing

```
[Int] :: *
```

Ok, that one follows pretty easily.

```
Int :: *
(->) :: * -> * -> *
[] :: * -> *

(->) Int :: * -> *
(->) Int Int :: *
```

Which is the same as

```
Int -> Int :: *
```

and therefore, by the same reasoning as above,

```
[Int -> Int] :: *
```

But here's a secret..  Take a closer look at the kind of `[]`.

```
[] :: * -> *
```

That means that it's a compile error to put any type inside a list that isn't of kind `*`.  And when you do provide it with something of kind `*`, the result will always have kind `*`.

Your confusion comes from not keeping levels separate. Many, many different types have the same kind.  After all, kind `*` more or less means "this type can have values". (There are some minor exceptions, but they're low-level internals things that you have to work quite hard to see.) If you can have a value of a type, it's a very good bet that the type has kind `*`.

Comment: Could you please say a bit more as to `(->) :: * -> * -> *`? I've never seen that symbol/function before. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @KevinMeredith `(->)` is the prefix form of the (normally infix) type constructor for functions. Functions aren't special in Haskell's type system. `Foo -> Bar` as a type can also be written as `(->) Foo Bar`. Just like anything else that's normally infix in haskell.

Answer (score 3):

The kind `*` stands for a concrete type. One way to think of a concrete type is that it doesn't take any type parameters. All of these are concrete types:

```
Int
Int -> Int
```

The type `[]` has kind `* -> *` -- it takes a concrete type and returns a concrete type.
Therefore both of these are concrete types (i.e. has kind `*`):

```
[ Int ]
[ Int -> Int ]
```

Comment: `One way to think of a concrete type is that it doesn't take any type parameters` - that's a very helpful thought - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In short, The kind `*` means a type. Any value , even function (functions are value) `Int`, `[Int]`, `Int -> [Int]` have a kind of `*`.

Types like Maybe are in fact a *type constructor*, they construct a new type from an existing type.
`Maybe Int` is a new type, `Maybe Float` another one etc ... wheresas.
So `Maybe` is a super function, which takes a type (for example `Int`) and returns an new one `Maybe Int`.
This is what `* -> *` means : take a type and return a new type. So `Maybe` is not a type itself, you can't use it by itself in a type signature, you need `Maybe a`, which is a type.

In the same way a 2-uple `(,)`, takes 2 types `a` and `b` and create a new one : `(a, b)`. It's kind is
`* -> * -> *` etc ...