# Creating a [Applicative Int]

Tags: haskell

Why can't I define a `[Applicative Int]` like so:

`Prelude Control.Applicative> let xs = [pure 5, pure 5] :: [Applicative Int]`

I get the following compile-time error, which I understand due to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24983642/same-kinds-for-list-of-int-compared-to-list-of-int-int).

```
<interactive>:60:43:
    Kind mis-match
    The first argument of `Applicative' should have kind `* -> *',
    but `Int' has kind `*'
    In an expression type signature: [Applicative Int]
    In the expression: [pure 5, pure 5] :: [Applicative Int]
    In an equation for `xs': xs = [pure 5, pure 5] :: [Applicative Int]
```

But, I'm not sure how to resolve this error.

Comment: `let xs = [pure 5, pure 5] :: Applicative f => [f Int]`. As @icktoofay says, `Applicative` is a type class, and `Applicative Int` is a constraint, not a 'type that has a value' (which is the only kind of type a normal list can contain).

Comment: Let's also note that `Applicative Int` is improperly typed; `Int` has kind `*`, while it should be `* -> *` if you want to use it with `Applicative :: (* -> *) -> Constraint`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`Applicative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Applicative) is a typeclass, not a type. You can have values of a type, and that type may even be an instance of a typeclass, but values must be associated with a type, and you’re saying that you want the values to have a typeclass rather than a type.

Some types that are instances of `Applicative` are

- `Maybe`
- `[]`
- `IO`

If you try running it using those types, it should work:

```
ghci> [pure 5, pure 5] :: [Maybe Int]
[Just 5, Just 5]
ghci> [pure 5, pure 5] :: [[Int]]
[[5], [5]]
ghci> sequence ([pure 5, pure 5] :: [IO Int])
[5, 5]
```

Answer (score 5):

`Applicative Int` is a (nonsensical, but let's ignore that for the moment) *constraint*. Constraints are not types. A constraint can never appear in an ordinary Haskell type, only in the *constraints* of a type signature. Normally, you have stuff like

```
anyEqual :: Eq a => a -> a -> a -> Bool
anyEqual a b c = a==b || a==c || b==c
```

or, perhaps more insightful here,

```
5 :: Num a => a
5 = 4 + 1
```

Notice that constraints basically make only sense when they include a type variable (`a` here). It is these constraints that *restrict `a` to the type class `Num`*.

It's important to understand that type classes are not like abstract classes you have in OO languages. It's not like, "`Eq` can be a type on it's own right and `Eq T` expresses that the compiler knows how to interpret a `T` object as an `Eq` object".
Rather, it's like this: `Eq` specifies a set of *methods* (for simplicity, say it's just `(==) :: a -> a -> Bool`). These methods are then given as an extra argument to an `Eq`-restricted polymorphic function: the *dictionary*. The internal implementation is something like

```
anyEqualBy :: (a->a->Bool) -> a->a->a->Bool
anyEqualBy eqFunc a b c = eqFunc a b || eqFunc a c || eqFunc b c
```

That explains a few things:

- `Applicative Int` is not really useful. The reason being, there is no type variable in it for which you might need a dictionary: if `Int` *was* in the applicative class, then the methods could simply all be inlined.
- It doesn't make sense to have the type of "list of constraint". Let's see what such a thing would need to translate to...

  ```
  anyEqualCrazy   :: [Eq a]       => a->a->a->Bool
  anyEqualCrazyBy :: [a->a->Bool] -> a->a->a->Bool
  ```

  so this would receive a whole list of dictionaries. That's something completely different from if the function would deal with *lists of some type*.